# Imagick roundCorners makes image half-transparant

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm in the process of writing an image script for a website I'm making, and for one of the image modes I need to both crop the image and make round corners for it. This is the code I'm using now:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($data);
$img->resizeImage($width, $height, $img->FILTER_GAUSSIAN, 1);
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage($size[0], $size[1], new ImagickPixel('white'));
$canvas->compositeImage($img, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$canvas->roundCorners(10, 10);
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');
```

[Resulting image](http://www.mikau.se/rounded.png)

However, the resulting image is about half-transparent, as seen above, except for a 10-ish px border around the edge, created by roundCorner I assume. I've tried a lot of different ways of doing this, including cropping $img directly and roundCorner on it, but then the result is without round corners.

I suspect compositeImage to be the thief in this drama, but I can't say for sure. Anyone?

EDIT: Correction: If I do the crop and round solution, I end up with rounded corners, but they have a black background. This is the code I'm using here. Anyone spot the error/solution?

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($data);
$img->resizeImage($width, $height, $img->FILTER_GAUSSIAN, 1);
$img->cropImage($size[0], $size[1], 0, 0);
$img->roundCorners(10, 10);
```

EDIT 2:
The solution to the crop and round resolution was to make sure it's a png, so that is has alpha-support. However, the result is the same as the one produced from my original code.

EDIT 3:
Tried this script on my deployment server, and it worked as I wanted it to, so it seems like there's some problem with the version of imagick / php-imagick shipped with macports. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: if you're presenting the images on a web page, you could use CSS to give them rounded corners. (and yes, that includes in IE, if you use CSS3Pie)

Comment: Sure I could, but I'd like the script to do this for me, since I might want to add extra effects based on those rounded corners, besides, it'd be fun to get it to work properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the version of Imagick / php-imagick shipped with current macports. Haven't solved it for my computer, but the script is working as intended on my deployment server.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell imagemagick to give you an alpha background with

```
$img->setImageAlphaChannel ( imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_TRANSPARENT )
```

or try setting the image format to PNG24 explicitly before doing any transformations.

Order is important here, the image needs an alpha channel *before* you expose the background.

Comment: Wow, missed the possibility that my images wasn't necessarily a png, so that fixed the difference in results between my versions. The original problem still stands thou :(